# Simulating the discharge of a condenser using CircuitLab

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, circuitlab

**Intro:**

While studying for a Signals and Systems exams for tomorrow i decided to simulate an exercise and prove my answers are right.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft8F2v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**What is it about?**

The exercise is to calculate the voltage and current at the inductor L1 when time is t=0 and foward (t>0).

*(The exercise asks for more but for the shake of simplicity i shorted the question)*

The capacitor has been charging for a long time (t<0) so we say it has a charge of 5volts.

**How can i simulate the discharge of the capacitor when the switch changed position?**

Comment: I don't have an answer for you off the top of my head, but I will note that "condenser" is a very, very old term for it; I've only ever seen it in books from first half of the 20th century. The modern term is "capacitor".

Comment: Hahahaha Well... it was a fast translation from my native language. Didn't mind if there is any difference for both terms. But that is not the question.

Comment: Oh, there's no difference in the terms to my knowledge, just thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: Condenser is still used in many areas :  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/222137/why-was-a-capacitor-called-a-condensor-condenser-in-the-early-days-of-electro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a time controlled switch and set it's time to 0. Choose a time domain simulation and click on the nodes you wish to plot (click on the wire leading to the inductor for the voltage and on the inductor 'pin' for current). Choose a time step and simulation time (you can experiment with it) and run the simulation.

I have done the above mentioned changes to your schematic and you can simulate it (click 'edit the above schematic' or 'simulate this circuit')

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7wd6r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUdaqz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The modified schematic.*

- Use the time-delay component.
- The simulator requires a ground reference.

[image]

*Figure 2. Time-delay settings.*

[image]

*Figure 3. The result.*